eBPF verifier error "unbounded variable-offset read" when read is safe and within bounds
I have an eBPF program where I want to compare the end of 2 strings:
    char buffer[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    int length = bpf_probe_read_str(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file_name) - 1;

    if (length < 0 || length >= (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)) {
        bpf_trace_printk("ERROR: Failed to read file name. \\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (ends_with(file->file_name, file->length, buffer, length)) {
        bpf_trace_printk("INFO: Accessed file: %s \\n", file->file_name)
    }

    return 0;

I've generated this code to do the comparison for each possible permutation of comparisons up to 32 characters unrolled. Here's an example of the generated code:
inline bool ends_with09(char needle[], const char haystack[], int haystack_length) {

    int haystack_start = haystack_length -  9;

    if (haystack_start < 0) {
        return false; 
    }

    return
      needle [0] == haystack[(haystack_start +  0)] &&
      needle [1] == haystack[(haystack_start +  1)] &&
      needle [2] == haystack[(haystack_start +  2)] &&
      needle [3] == haystack[(haystack_start +  3)] &&
      needle [4] == haystack[(haystack_start +  4)] &&
      needle [5] == haystack[(haystack_start +  5)] &&
      needle [6] == haystack[(haystack_start +  6)] &&
      needle [7] == haystack[(haystack_start +  7)] &&
      needle [8] == haystack[(haystack_start +  8)];
};

inline bool ends_with(char needle[], u8 needle_length, char haystack[], int haystack_length) {

    switch (needle_length) {

      case  1: return ends_with01(needle, haystack, haystack_length);
      case  2: return ends_with02(needle, haystack, haystack_length);
      /* ... more generated code ... */
      case  9: return ends_with09(needle, haystack, haystack_length);
      /* ... more generated code ... */
      case 31: return ends_with31(needle, haystack, haystack_length);
      case 32: return ends_with32(needle, haystack, haystack_length);
      default: return false;
    }
};

However, the verifier constantly is giving me an error like the following:
invalid unbounded variable-offset read from stack R2

Or:
R2 invalid mem access 'scalar'

Even if I add a check to verify that haystack_start + 8 >= haystack_length (which is always false), the program still fails to verify:
inline bool ends_with09(char needle[], const char haystack[], int haystack_length) {

    int haystack_start = haystack_length -  9;

    if (haystack_start < 0 || haystack_start + 8 >= haystack_length) {
        return false; 
    }

    return
      needle [0] == haystack[(haystack_start +  0)] &&
      needle [1] == haystack[(haystack_start +  1)] &&
      needle [2] == haystack[(haystack_start +  2)] &&
      needle [3] == haystack[(haystack_start +  3)] &&
      needle [4] == haystack[(haystack_start +  4)] &&
      needle [5] == haystack[(haystack_start +  5)] &&
      needle [6] == haystack[(haystack_start +  6)] &&
      needle [7] == haystack[(haystack_start +  7)] &&
      needle [8] == haystack[(haystack_start +  8)];
};


Did you consider using the bpf_strncmp helper?

Bitwise ANDing each byte read access works, but it will increase overhead (at runtime and in terms of complexity).
Instead, I think you should be able to perform a single check, as follows:
inline bool ends_with09(char needle[], const char haystack[], int haystack_length) {

    int haystack_start = haystack_length -  9;

    if (haystack_start < 0 || haystack_start >= MAX_FILE_LEN)
        return false;

    return memcmp(needle, haystack + haystack_start, 8) == 0;
};


The verifier doesn't know that you are safely accessing the data because of the variable length returned from bpf_probe_read_str. Instead it sees that you are accessing data from a buffer and you might be reading outside the buffer's boundaries (even though that's not possible given your code). In The art of writing eBPF programs: a primer., Gianluca Borello describes how to convince the verifier that your code is safe.
Bitwise ANDing your access/index with the max possible buffer index:
needle [8] == haystack[(haystack_start +  8) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)]

So the generated code looks like:
inline bool ends_with09(char needle[], const char haystack[], int haystack_length) {

    int haystack_start = haystack_length -  9;

    if (haystack_start < 0) {
        return false; 
    }

    return
      needle [0] == haystack[(haystack_start +  0) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [1] == haystack[(haystack_start +  1) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [2] == haystack[(haystack_start +  2) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [3] == haystack[(haystack_start +  3) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [4] == haystack[(haystack_start +  4) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [5] == haystack[(haystack_start +  5) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [6] == haystack[(haystack_start +  6) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [7] == haystack[(haystack_start +  7) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)] &&
      needle [8] == haystack[(haystack_start +  8) & (MAX_FILE_NAME - 1)];
};

Then the verifier will know that you are not overrunning the bounds of the buffer.
